# How much information should I display to the user on failed login?

Tags: security, authentication

If a user attempts to login to my site (username and password), but fails, should I display *what* field(s) were incorrect? Or, should I simply state that their credentials were invalid?

If I am dealing with a legitimate user, it would be more helpful to show them what fields were incorrect. But, if an illegitimate user is attempting to breach login, it would be more secure to only display that credentials were invalid.

So, I'm wondering if there is an established answer to this question. Are there any known best-practices for dealing with this issue? Or, is it a matter of taking the known pros and cons and deciding based upon the sensitivity of the site?

Comment: are there any fields other than user and password in your login page?

Comment: @Oren A: username, password, and remember me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the best practice is to respond that the combination of username / password was  not correct.  This is considered best practice for public facing logins.  If you are dealing with an intranet site you may be able to provide more information.

If you were to respond that the username was correct but the password was wrong you are allowing malicious users to know they have a valid username and from there go on to guess the password.

Answer (score 0):

After having numerous "ethical hacks" performed on sites I've worked on the recommendation has always been display as little as possible.  So, if either user name or password fails just display something like "Login failed".

Answer (score 0):

I think that if a user got either wrong, that can mean he got the other wrong as well, and so you should tell him to "recheck everything".

Also, if you'll notify the user either username or password was wrong, meaning the other was right, if he's a malicious user, you're helping him.